# Send tapAction from SwiftUI button action to UIView function

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm trying to find a way to trigger an action that will call a function in my `UIView` when a button gets tapped inside `swiftUI`.

> Here's my setup:

*`foo()(UIView)` needs to run when `Button(SwiftUI)` gets tapped*

#### My custom UIView class making use of AVFoundation frameworks

```swift
class SomeView: UIView {

    func foo() {}
}
```

#### To use my UIView inside swiftUI I have to wrap it in `UIViewRepresentable`

```swift
struct SomeViewRepresentable: UIViewRepresentable {

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> CaptureView {
        SomeView()
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: CaptureView, context: Context) {        
    }
}
```

#### SwiftUI View that hosts my UIView()

```swift
struct ContentView : View {

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 24) {
            SomeViewRepresentable()
                .background(Color.gray)
            HStack {
                Button(action: {
                    print("SwiftUI: Button tapped")
                   // Call func in SomeView()
                }) {
                    Text("Tap Here")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can look at my answer to a similar question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/70559743/5379093

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can store an instance of your custom `UIView` in your representable struct (`SomeViewRepresentable` here) and call its methods on tap actions:

```
struct SomeViewRepresentable: UIViewRepresentable {

  let someView = SomeView() // add this instance

  func makeUIView(context: Context) -> SomeView { // changed your CaptureView to SomeView to make it compile
    someView
  }

  func updateUIView(_ uiView: SomeView, context: Context) {

  }

  func callFoo() {
    someView.foo()
  }
}
```

And your view body will look like this:

```
  let someView = SomeViewRepresentable()

  var body: some View {
    VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 24) {
      someView
        .background(Color.gray)
      HStack {
        Button(action: {
          print("SwiftUI: Button tapped")
          // Call func in SomeView()
          self.someView.callFoo()
        }) {
          Text("Tap Here")
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

To test it I added a print to the `foo()` method:

```
class SomeView: UIView {

  func foo() {
    print("foo called!")
  }
}
```

Now tapping on your button will trigger `foo()` and the print statement will be shown.

Comment: Can't believe it's so simple. Don't know why I thought it would be different. 
Thanks a lot 

Comment: DAMN! I've spent today trying to just this - push or trigger something in `UIKit` from `SwiftUI` and actually created a question a few minutes ago. It's now deleted. I just wish I could give you more than one upvote.

Comment: Haha that simple eh? 

Comment: keeping a reference to uiview give me some weird effects we it redraws the uiview

Comment: It is working but adding this instance variable caused Update requests to keep being sent forever. When I remove it, it is not called.

My UIView is MKMapView which may be different.

Comment: Not a perfect solution. What if SomeViewRepresentable need some parameters to initialize that are globally available in you SwiftUI view struct. It will not work then

Answer (score 8):

M Reza's solution works for simple situations, however if your parent SwiftUI view has state changes, every time when it refreshes, it will cause your UIViewRepresentable to create new instance of UIView because of this: `let someView = SomeView() // add this instance`. Therefore `someView.foo()` is calling the action on the previous instance of `SomeView` you created, which is already outdated upon refreshing, so you might not see any updates of your UIViewRepresentable appear on your parent view.
See: https://medium.com/zendesk-engineering/swiftui-uiview-a-simple-mistake-b794bd8c5678

A better practice would be to avoid creating and referencing that instance of UIView when calling its function.

My adaption to M Reza's solution would be calling the function indirectly through parent view's state change, which triggers `updateUIView` :

```
  var body: some View {
    @State var buttonPressed: Bool = false
    VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 24) {

      //pass in the @State variable which triggers actions in updateUIVIew
      SomeViewRepresentable(buttonPressed: $buttonPressed)
        .background(Color.gray)
      HStack {
        Button(action: {
          buttonPressed = true
        }) {
          Text("Tap Here")
        }
      }
    }
  }

struct SomeViewRepresentable: UIViewRepresentable {
  @Binding var buttonPressed: Bool 

  func makeUIView(context: Context) -> SomeView {
    return SomeView()
  }

  //called every time buttonPressed is updated
  func updateUIView(_ uiView: SomeView, context: Context) {
    if buttonPressed {
        //called on that instance of SomeView that you see in the parent view
        uiView.foo()
        buttonPressed = false
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This should be the more correct answer since this is the correct way to do it in SwiftUI .... the mindset of doing things in SwiftUI is much more different than the traditional UIKit.

Comment: This causes ->  [SwiftUI] Modifying state during view update, this will cause undefined behavior.

This is because you set the buttonPressed to false in your update block again.

Comment: Wrap `buttonPressed = false` in `DispatchQueue.main.async` to avoid the warning. It's important to update view state only on the main thread.

Answer (score 3):

Here is yet another solution! Communicate between the superview and the `UIViewRepresentable` using a closure:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    
    /// This closure will be initialized in our subview
    @State var closure: (() -> Void)?
    
    var body: some View {
        SomeViewRepresentable(closure: $closure)
        Button("Tap here!") {
            closure?()
        }
    }
}
```

Then initialize the closure in the `UIViewRepresentable`:

```swift
struct SomeViewRepresentable: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    // This is the same closure that our superview will call
    @Binding var closure: (() -> Void)?
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
        
        let uiView = UIView()
        
        // Since `closure` is part of our state, we can only set it on the main thread
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            closure = {
                // Perform some action on our UIView
            }
        }
        return uiView
    }
}
```

Comment: After trying all available answers, this is what worked for me perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way to do it using a bridging class.

```
//SwiftUI
struct SomeView: View{
  var bridge: BridgeStuff?

  var body: some View{
    Button("Click Me"){
      bridge?.yo()
    }
  }
}

//UIKit or AppKit (use NS instead of UI)
class BridgeStuff{
  var yo:() -> Void = {}
}

class YourViewController: UIViewController{

  override func viewDidLoad(){
    let bridge = BridgeStuff()
    let view = UIHostingController(rootView: SomeView(bridge: bridge))
    bridge.yo = { [weak self] in
      print("Yo")
      self?.howdy()
    }
  }

  func howdy(){
    print("Howdy")
  }
}
```

Comment: This is a great idea, but technically the question is asking about `UIViewRepresentable` and not `UIHostingController`. I've taken this idea and adjusted it to work with `UIViewRepresentable` in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72591441/15959847).

Answer (score 2):

@ada10086 has a great answer. Just thought I'd provide an alternative solution that would be more convenient if you want to send many different actions to your `UIView`.

The key is to use [`PassthroughSubject`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/passthroughsubject) from `Combine` to send messages from the superview to the `UIViewRepresentable`.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    
    /// This will act as a messenger to our subview
    private var messenger = PassthroughSubject<String, Never>()
    
    var body: some View {
        SomeViewRepresentable(messenger: messenger)  // Pass the messenger to our subview
        Button("Tap here!") {
            // Send a message
            messenger.send("button-tapped")
        }
    }
}
```

Then we monitor the `PassthroughSubject` in our subview:

```swift
struct SomeViewRepresentable: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    let messenger = PassthroughSubject<String, Never>()
    @State private var subscriptions: Set<AnyCancellable> = []
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
        
        let uiView = UIView()
        
        // This must be run on the main thread
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            // Subscribe to messages
            messenger.sink { message in
                switch message {
                    // Call funcs in `uiView` depending on which message we received
                }
            }
            .store(in: &subscriptions)
        }
        return uiView
    }
}
```

This approach is nice because you can send any string to the subview, so you can design a whole messaging scheme.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to create an intermediary `SomeViewModel` object. The object stores an optional closure, which is assigned an action when `SomeView` is created.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    // parent view holds the state object
    @StateObject var someViewModel = SomeViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 24) {
            SomeViewRepresentable(model: someViewModel)
                .background(Color.gray)
            HStack {
                Button {
                    someViewModel.foo?()
                } label: {
                    Text("Tap Here")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct SomeViewRepresentable: UIViewRepresentable {
    @ObservedObject var model: SomeViewModel

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> SomeView {
        let someView = SomeView()
        // we don't want the model to hold on to a reference to 'someView', so we capture it with the 'weak' keyword
        model.foo = { [weak someView] in
            someView?.foo()
        }
        return someView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: SomeView, context: Context) {

    }
}

class SomeViewModel: ObservableObject {
    var foo: (() -> Void)? = nil
}
```

Three benefits doing it this way:

1. We avoid the original problem that @ada10086 identified with @m-reza's solution; creating the view only within the `makeUIView` function, [as per the guidance from Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/uiviewrepresentable/makeuiview(context:)), which state that we "must implement this method and use it to create your view object."
2. We avoid the problem that @orschaef identified with @ada10086's alternative solution; we're not modifying state during a view update.
3. By using `ObservableObject` for the model, we can add `@Published` properties to the model and communicate state changes from the `UIView` object. For instance, if `SomeView` uses KVO for some of its properties, we can create an observer that will update some `@Published` properties, which will be propagated to any interested SwiftUI views.