# SwiftUI send action from a page to the PageViewController

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uipageviewcontroller, uiviewcontrollerrepresentable

I have set up a `PageViewController` in SwiftUI, following the known Tutorial [Interfacing with UIKit](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/interfacing-with-uikit), with `UIViewControllerRepresentable` etc.

My array of controllers consists of simple SwiftUI views. I pass a simple `IntroPage` struct to supply the content. The views are nested, as is good SwiftUI practice, thus:

```
PageView
-   IntroScreen                // part of the pages array
    -   VStack 
        -   Text
        -   Image
        -   ButtonView         // a separate view struct
            - HStack
                - ForEach      // iterating through the buttons in my IntroPage Object
                    - Button
PageControl
```

Now I want to include some **buttons** on these views. They should be configurable via my `IntroPage` struct. One of them advances to the next page in the PageViewController, another tells the PageViewController to add more pages first, another button dismisses the entire PageViewController.

I cannot figure out, how get access to these methods in the PageViewController, where to implement them (the instance view? the coordinator of the PageViewController?) and how to reach the objects I need (e.g. the `currentPage` Binding variable of the PageViewController).

For example, I have implemented a `forward()` function in the PageViewController's coordinator:

```
func forward() {
   if parent.currentPage < parent.controllers.count - 1 {
       parent.currentPage += 1
   }
}
```

...which works fine, with animations and all, if I add a button right beside the PageView on my final View. But I still cannot call this from the button contained in the child view.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:** Upon request, here is a situation in the ButtonView.

```swift
struct IntroButtonView: View {
    var page: IntroPage
    var body: some View {
        HStack() {
           Button(action:dismiss) {
              Text("LocalizedButtonTitle")
           }
           // ... more buttons, based on certain conditions
        }
    }

    func dismiss() { 
         // how to dismiss the modally presented controller ?
    }

    func next()    { 
         // how to advance to the next page
    }

    func expand()  { 
         // how to add more pages to the pages array
    }
}
```

Or maybe I am completely wrong and still think in terms of "events" rather than "declaration"...

Comment: Would you just show in code from what to what you need to call a function?

Comment: Added some code for clarity.

Comment: You can look at my answer to a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70559743/5379093

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I figured it out. Not intuitive at first, I have to say. Coming from traditional event based programming, it's quite a different way of thinking

I used a `@State` variable in the main instance of the view.

I used `@Binding` variables to deal with the state both upstream (ViewControllers, Controls) and downstream (subviews). So, for example, I used a variable to tell the `dataSource` of the `UIPageViewController` if or not to return a view controller before/after the current one.

For the dismissing the modally presented controller I used

```
@Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode

...

func dismiss() {
  self.presentationMode.wrapptedValue.dismiss()
}
```

Similarly,

```
...
@Binding var currentPage: int
...

Button(action: next) { Text("Next Page") }
...

...
func next() {
    currentPage += 1
}
```

There were a few caveats in deciding how to nest the views and what variables to pick for the bindings, but it is clear to me now. The biggest problem was ultimately where the "source of truth" should be anchored. It turned out, right in the "middle", i.e. below the controller and above the particular views.

Hope this is useful for others looking for something similar.

Comment: if you think you have solved your issue please select this as the answer @Mundi

Comment: I am still waiting for other suggestions.

Comment: Could you tell how to move to next page from a button action inside the ContentView in the Pagecontrolelr?

Comment: @BhuvanBhatt I edited my answer to provide more details on this case.